# How to pick best model based on Accuracy and Recall in a GridSearchCV when you have already set scoring = custom_scorer?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

This is a binary classification problem, I am using a GridSearchCV from Sklearn to find the best model, here is the GridSearch line I am using:

```
 scoring = {'AUCe': 'roc_auc', 'Accuracy': 'accuracy', 'prec':  'precision', 'rec': 'recall', 'f1s': 'f1','spec':make_scorer(recall_score,pos_label=0)}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=cv, scoring=scoring, refit='Accuracy')
```

All is fine, but, my problem is that I want the model to be picked based on both highest Accuracy and Recall, I know that in order to sort the values and pick the best model based on a specific metric, I have to set `refit =  'Accuracy'`, I also read on sklearn that refit can also be set to bool, str, or **callable**, and here is where my problem lies

I have read that if you use a custom scorer for scoring parameter, you lose the ability to use a custom refit, this is the article: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17058

As you can see from my code above, I used a multimetric scoring, how can I set refit to be based on Accuracy and Recall while still having multimetric scoring ability, currently I am printing cv_results_ tables in pandas dataframe, sorting each group of different models by Accuracy and Recall, then picking the highest one and applying it on my hold-out testing data, now this gets tedious if you have to first apply GridSearch on first similar sets of models, then take the best model from every one, then compare them again.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Afaik `refit` is just a convenience option which directly fits a new model on the whole data with the best parameters, so you could as well do it manually just after the call to `GridSearchCV`. However I'm not sure that you've clearly defined how you want the parameters to be picked: for example what do you want to happen if parameters A give accuracy .9, recall .6 and parameters B give acuracy .8, recall .8?

Comment: @Erwan I really have not thought of this possibility yet, here is what I can think of right now, my primary focus will be on Accuracy, while I define an acceptable threshold of how much is considered a good recall i.e >= .8, like in this example, .9 with a recall of .6 will be below the threshold that I will pick, and thus, will prompt me to try and balance the data in a way where the recall is above or equal to said threshold, most of my results regarding recall is .7 and above

Comment: My understanding from [the doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) is that `refit` can be used with a custom function, but I haven't tried. But I don't really understand why it would be an issue to fit a new model on the whole data after `GridSearchCV` (of course you must have defined a deterministic way to pick the best hyper-parameters).

Comment: @Erwan it is not really an issue for me to fit the best parameter as a new model, it was just that I was trying to automate the work, and since I got paranoid about metrics, I was concerned that maybe the automated part is going to pick the first model it sees from two models that have the same accuracy but different recall one with a better recall, as this adds a randomness in picking. My main Issue is that you cannot use a custom refit if you have already used a custom scoring,  unless I am doing something wrong, refit does have a say on which model to consider the best model.

Comment: To be honest I don't completely understand the issue, but the way I usually proceed when in doubt is to implement things myself: technically the grid search CV process is made of a few nested loops for the hyper-parameters with CV happening inside. At the end of the grid search you can obtain the best parameters following your own method and fit the final model. It might not be the most efficient way but it gives you control of everything.